# Create A singletonSet Function Which Creates A Singleton Set From One Integer Value In SCALA

Tags: scala

I've been asked to create a singletonSet function which creates a singleton set from one integer value:
The code I used:

```
    def singletonSet(elem: Int): Set = {
    def isInSet (givenElement: Int) = 

          if (elem == givenElement) true
          else false

     isInSet
  }
```

checking online somebody did:

```
  def singletonSet(elem: Int): Set = {
    x => List(elem).contains(x)
  }
```

does that mean he/she put the element in a list and called the .contains() function on it?
and I don't get what x does here? I tried this code. It runs with no error. I just don't get it. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

As I understand

```
type Set = Int => Boolean
```

So x is just an Int that the returned function applies.

> does that mean he/she put the element in a list and called the
>   .contains() function on it?

Yes it looks so and we can simplify it:

```
  def singletonSet(elem: Int): Int => Boolean  = {
    x:Int => elem == x:Boolean
  }
```

Let's remove types

```
  def singletonSet(elem: Int): Int => Boolean = {
    x => elem == x
  }
```

and replace x with placeholder _

```
def singletonSet(elem: Int) = elem == (_:Int)
```

Comment: so this is my whole innerFunction: `x:Int => elem == x:Boolean` which you turned it to `x => elem == x` or let's say `Int=>Boolean`. but how about the other function. ` x => List(elem).contains(x)` can we say it takes x and applies `.contains(x)` to a List of (elem)s. what I see from this definition is `(x:Int) => List(elem).contains(x):Boolean`. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, it takes x and applies .contains(x).
(x:Int) => List(elem).contains(x) means List(elem).contains(_:Int)

Answer (score 0):

I imagine the Set you are defining here is not a scala.immutable.Set trait right? Regarding the code, calling `List(something)` basically calls the `apply` method on the `List` companion object to create an immutable List.

The function `singletonSet` basically returns a higher order function that takes an element named x and returns a boolean, but I don't think that piece of code compiles as it is missing type information on the x parameter.

Comment: The set that we are talking about is a type that we defined `type Set = Int => Boolean` and there is no mention about if it needs to be mutable or immutable.

Comment: Then yes, he is putting an element in a new List and calling the contains on it, so the function that is returning is of type `Set` as it takes an element int, and returns a boolean (The result of calling the contains method)